# How to Interpret 認不真 in 須認真. 若認不真. 便都成了假的?

Tags: literary-chinese

The context is the reader has just been told that in [blank] he 須認真.

> [blank]須認真. 若**認不真**. 便都成了假的.

What puzzles me is the 不 in the middle of 認真.  I understand that each character by itself is a word, but it seems generally to be one two character word, "earnest".  Is the 不 negating one of two words, or half of one word, or all of a two character word?  I've never seen that.

Comment: see grammar on potential complements/可能补语： 认真 to take seriously，to take to heart: verb  认 + complement of result 真, 認不真 : verb  认 + potential complement 不真 meaning action not possible, thus 須認真.若認不真, e.g. it is necessary to take it seriously, if it cannot be taken seriously (then 便都成了假的)

Comment: web search seems to indicate that the sequence 認不真 indeed is uncommon, comment #1 may be justified by grammar of potential complement

Comment: regarding answer #1 note bkrs: 认真：2) 当真。
红楼梦．第五十九回：「打了干的打亲的。还是卖弄你女儿多，还是认真不知王法？」认假不认真 accept falsehood/ take falsehood seriously, but not truth, bkrs has the potential complement construction 听不真, but just like 认不真 users cannot find any other examples on the web of 听不真,

Answer (score 2):

「認真」is a common two characters compound word. It means 'serious' (adj.) 
Since it is an adjective, we can add the negative function word 「不」(not ) before it, and form an negative phrase  「不認真」(not serious)

However, 「認」on it's own can be the verb 'identify' or ' 'recognize' as in 「認人」(identify a person)，「認路」(recognize the way);  while 「真」on it's own can be the adjective 'true' or 'accurate' ; or the adverb 'truly' or 'accurately'

As a simple grammatical rule, an adverb can modify a verb.
Which mean 「認真」 can be treated as a [verb+ adverb] structure instead of a compound that we are familiar with.

In the case of 「認不真」，「不」being a negative function word that modifies the adverb 「真」make it clear that the term we are looking at, is in fact [verb+ 不 + adverb] structure (認+不+真).

If 「不」 is placed before 「認真」, that would make it an [不 + adjective] structure (不+認真).

- 「不認真」means 'not serious'
- 「認不真」means 'cannot identify accurately' or 'not identify accurately'

As I mentioned before, 「認真」is a very common 'word' , to avoid confusion, it is better use 「認不清」 instead of 「認不真」.

I believe if the phrase in question was 「認不真確」instead of the shortened 「認不真」, you would not be so confused.

Since the common word 「認真」is widely used, putting 認 and 真 in a [verb + adverb] structure would certainly cause confusion. It is not recommended.

> 須**認真**.若**認不真**. 便都成了假的.

In this context **須認真** means " **Need to identify accurately**.

> " Need to **identify accurately**. If **not identify accurately**, then everything will become (be treated as) fake"

I would suggest phrasing it as 「須認(得)真(確), 若認不真(確),  便都成了假的」 to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is text written and published by someone else; I'm trying to understand the structure, rewriting it is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

可能缺了一个了字，认不（了）真。意思是：我现在好烦，我认真不起来。